# Make sounds from photoresistor on arduino using MIDI on garageband?

Tags: arduino, midi

I'm having trouble trying to make sounds from my photoresistor using MIDI. I have a MIDISPORT USB. I connected MIDI OUT from my breadboard from the MIDI JACK and my MIDI IN isn't connected to anything because I don't know where it should go or if I should just leave it. I'm using Hairless MIDI serial program to connect my arduino with MIDI, they seem to receiving signal from my usb on the arduino side and the Midi side but I don't hear any sounds.

How does garageband come in to this? It doesn't have to be garageband, i just want to make this work and hear the sounds. I made sure garageband is connected to MIDI as well as having HairlessMIDI at serial 9600 and my arduino at serial.begin at 9600. everything seems to look good so far. I just don't know why I don't hear anything. Am I supposed to hear it from garageband, if so how?

here's my arduino code,

```
byte noteON = 144;//note on command

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  MIDImessage(noteON, 60, 100);//turn note on
  delay(300);//hold note for 300ms
  MIDImessage(noteON, 60, 0);//turn note off (note on with velocity 0)
  delay(200);//wait 200ms until triggering next note
}

//send MIDI message
void MIDImessage(byte command, byte data1, byte data2) {
  Serial.write(command);
  Serial.write(data1);
  Serial.write(data2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your setup correctly, you use:

- an arduino with a sensor to generate a signal, this is the instrument
- MIDISPORT USB http://www.performanceaudio.com/media/pdf/121/3757_m.pdf to make the link between the instrument and the computer
- HairlessMIDI which converts a serial text protocol to midi. http://projectgus.github.io/hairless-midiserial/#getting_started

I am unsure you need the MIDISPORT at all. HairlessMIDI already makes the link between an Arduino program and a MIDI expander application (see tutorial in the link above).

According to this page, the Arduino must use the [MIDI](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/MIDILibrary) Library, and the init code looks like this.

```
void setup() {
  MIDI.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
```

Note the 115200 baud rate. The serial port on Arduinos must use a specific baudrate, otherwise the host and slave won't be able to talk to each other.

I think you must connect your setup to the MIDI In side on the HairlessMIDI application. If GarageBand is running, you must be able to select it in the drop down list.